# image not full width in a col-md-4 div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to make an image full width in col-md-4 div. I've tried using the img-responsive class as well as width:100% but still it is not working. below is my html code and css

### HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 travelinfo">

  <h3>travel info</h3>
  <div class="col-md-4 smallImg">
    <img src="img/pokhara.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 NewsInfo">
    <a href="">The six best trekking routes </a>
    <p> March 22,2012</p>
  </div><div class="clear-fix"></div><br>



  <div class="col-md-4 smallImg">
    <img src="img/illam.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 NewsInfo">
    <a href="">amazing places </a>
    <p>may 30,2011</p>
  </div><div class="clear-fix"></div><br>


  <div class="col-md-4 smallImg">
    <img src="img/langtang.jpeg" class="img-responsive">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 NewsInfo">
    <a href="">amazing langtang and gosaikund</a>
    <p>april 2015</p>
  </div><div class="clear-fix"></div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
.travelinfo .smallImg img{margin-top:25px;float: left;max-width: 100%;vertical-align: middle;}
.NewsInfo{float: right;line-height: 15px;margin-top: 20px;}

.NewsInfo a{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 13px;color:#fff; text-transform:uppercase;font-weight: 400;}
.NewsInfo p{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 13px;color:#ff590b; text-transform:uppercase;}
```

Comment: Can you add which framework and/or external styles are you using?

Comment: `col-md-4` usually have some `padding-left` and right, this may be the cause that the width doesn't fit on the container. Double check the size of the image too, because if the container has 500px and the image less than 500, it won't fill the entire container (because you set max-width and not width)

Comment: i used padding: 0 !important; and the image is full width now. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this css code to make image full width within a `col-md-4` div.

```
 .smallImg img{width:100%}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-4 smallImg">
    <img src="img/langtang.jpeg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
</div>
```

Don't miss `alt=""` for better practice.

CSS:

```
.smallImg img
{
    width:100%;
}
```